# What is the flow of USN journal update?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I'm trying to understand flow of writes to a file on NTFS partition - when exactly USN is updated?

Let's imagine 4K random write workload (e.g. from CrystalDiskMark). In this case does NTFS update USN with every write? It seems to be bottleneck, especially with multiple threads as each thread needs some exclusive access to the USN (locks?).